# Google analytics date format

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to obtain data via the Google analytics api (Java). Every half an hour once I would be running a script which needs to get me the required variables over the previous half an hour, that is details of the person who has used my site over the last half hour. I do not know if this is possible since the start date and end date parameters can be used only in date format and not in datetime format. How should I proceed with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Google has a realtime api that allows you to get a limited set of dimensions and metrics for the last 30 minutes. The regular API will not give you values for the last hour at all since processing time is between 4 to 24 hours. So depending on which values you want to display this might not be possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics core reporting API provides 2 dimensions which are the hour and the minute. This should allow you to accomplish what you want, just make sure to wait till the hour and minute you are querying are updated.

Check

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_hour